# trying to fetch data into view , not sure if am doing it right

Tags: laravel

I would like to let the current logged in user to input  the year and term and based  on that fetch the relevant records from database....cant seem to fetch desired data when i search through the form i get an error

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'term'
     in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join
    `cat1s` on `users`.`id` = `cat1s`.`user_id` inner join `cat2s` on
    `users`.`id` = `cat2s`.`user_id` inner join `exams` on `users`.`id` =
    `exams`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = 21 and `term` = 1) "
```

View

```
{{Form::open(['method'=>'GET','route'=>'results'])}}
         <ul>
           <li>{{Form::label('year','year of study')}}
              {{Form::text('year', null, array("placeholder" => "year"))}}
              {{--{{$errors->first('reg_no','<p class = "error">:message</p>')}}--}}
           </li>
           <li>{{Form::label('term','term')}}
               {{ Form::text('term', null, array("placeholder" => "term")) }}
               {{--{{$errors->first('firstname','<p class = "error">:message</p>')}}--}}
           </li>
            <li>
               {{Form::submit('search')}}
            </li>
         </ul>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Route

```
Route::get('results', ['as' => 'results', 'uses' => 'Cat1sController@show']);
```

Controller

```
public function show()

                {
        $year = Input::get('year');
                $term = Input::get('term');
            $maks=DB::table('users')
                                ->join('cat1s','users.id' , '=', 'cat1s.user_id' )
                                ->join('cat2s','users.id' , '=','cat2s.user_id')
                                ->join('exams','users.id' , '=','exams.user_id' )
                         ->where('users.id','=', Auth::user()->id )                   
                         ->where('term','LIKE',[$term] AND 'year',[$year])
                         ->get();
                         return View::make('pages.result',compact('maks'));
            }
```

Part of pages.result view

```
<table>
                               @foreach($maks as $mak)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$ENG}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$MATH}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$BIO}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$CHEM}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$PHY}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$COMP}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$MUSIC}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$ART}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$TOTAL}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$AVRG}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$GRADE}}</td>
                                        <td> {{$mak->$POSTN}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 @endforeach
                         </table>
```

Comment: AFTER EDITING TO THIS...{->where('cat1s.year','LIKE',[$year] AND 'cat1s.term',[$term])  } i get Array to string conversion ERROR can't really fig out.....any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to add the prefix of the table who contain 'term' in your sql request

```
 $maks=DB::table('users')
                    ->join('cat1s','users.id' , '=', 'cat1s.user_id' )
                    ->join('cat2s','users.id' , '=','cat2s.user_id')
                    ->join('exams','users.id' , '=','exams.user_id' )
             ->where('users.id','=', Auth::user()->id )                   
             ->where('**table.**term','LIKE',[$term] AND '**table.**year',[$year])
             ->get();
```

**Edit 1**
**To dump your data :**

`@foreach( $maks as $mak ) {
    <tr>
    <?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($mak); echo '</pre>'; ?>
    {# rest of your code #}
    </tr>
@endforeach`

You have the "Array to string conversion" error because $mak should be a string, and it contain one of more array.
Blade templating : {{ $var }} is like `<?php echo $var; ?>`
And you cannot echo an array, but you can reformat your data . Show me the dump of `$mak` and i give you the snippet

Comment: just did that now getting an error: Array to string conversion

Comment: Try to var_dump($mak) in your foreach and post the result.
It's because in var $mak you should have only string but there is an array

Comment: still after var _dump($mak) the same error...maybe u could kindly illustrate with some code snippet{...}

Comment: THATS ALL IT'S DISPLAYING     ErrorException (E_NOTICE)

Array to string conversion                                                               foreach ($query->wheres as $where)
  {
   $method = "where{$where['type']}";
 
   $sql[] = $where['boolean'].' '.$this->$method($query, $where);
  }

Comment: I've edited my answer check this and give me feedback

Comment: its not dumping  changed to .....->where('cat1s.year','LIKE','%year%' AND 'cat1s.term','%term%') rather than vars is this correct or  ->where('cat1s.year','LIKE','?' AND 'cat1s.term','>=?') what's the correct syntax

Comment: It's another problem, please vote for an answer and re-open a question with all the elements to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
->where('term','LIKE',[$term] AND 'year',[$year])
```

to, this:

```
->where('users.term','LIKE',[$term] AND 'your_table.year',[$year])
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error indicates that there are multiple columns named `term` among tables you're trying to query. So add specific table name prefix to column name e.g. `users.term`.

The other problem is in line:

```
->where('term','LIKE',[$term] AND 'year',[$year])
```

Which is completely incorrect.